# Wordpress Fatal error: Cannot access empty property

Tags: wordpress, prefix

Hy,

This piece of code worked local, but as soon as i uploaded it to an test server, it was buggy. I'm new to wordpress plugins, but i know how php works.

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot access empty property
```

And this is the line that gives the error (the last line):

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb -> show_errors();
$dbPrefixHere = $wpdb -> $prefix;
```

Am i'm doing something wrong here? Or is there en better / nicer way to get the db prefix?

**edit 1**
alright, i've got that working, but now there is no db table created...

I'm using this part of code for that:

```
$sQueryCheckProjectDB = "CREATE TABLE ".$dbPrefixHere."automaticthesiswriter_projects (
                          projectID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                          userID int(11) NOT NULL,
                          shareID int(11) NOT NULL,
                          projectName mediumtext NOT NULL,
                          projectDescription mediumtext NOT NULL,
                          PRIMARY KEY  (projectID)
                        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;";
dbDelta($sqlUseOnPageSQLCreate);
```

But the table isn't created, and there is no error showed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing:

```
$dbPrefixHere = $wpdb -> $prefix;
```

to:

```
$dbPrefixHere = $wpdb->prefix;
```

Additional answer: (incorrect variable used?)

```
$sQueryCheckProjectDB = "CREATE TABLE ".$dbPrefixHere."automaticthesiswriter_projects (
                          projectID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                          userID int(11) NOT NULL,
                          shareID int(11) NOT NULL,
                          projectName mediumtext NOT NULL,
                          projectDescription mediumtext NOT NULL,
                          PRIMARY KEY  (projectID)
                        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;";
dbDelta($sQueryCheckProjectDB);
```

refernce: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

Comment: alright, that worked, but now something else don't work. i've updated the question... do you know an fix?

Comment: Haha, how could i be so blind to not see that...
wel, thank you verry much :D